# Parse math expression elements from string to list

Tags: python, parsing

if I have a

```
string = '((a * 5) // ((10 - y) + z))'
```

and I just want to remove the `a`, `5`, `10`, `y`, `z`, and put them in

```
lst1 = []
```

and I also want to remove the `*`, `-`, `+` and put them in

```
lst2 = []
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: In list1 output the `//` should be a single element I assume?

Comment: I have tried a for loop but it doesn't work for the 10. The for loop works as long as the numbers are between 0 and 9.

Comment: If you are in the beginning stages of trying to write a parser, stop now and google Shunting-Yard Algorithm.

Comment: if the syntax is Python, you could [use `ast` module to parse it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4279) e.g., `print(ast.dump(ast.parse('((a * 5) // ((10 - y) + z))', mode='eval')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions (the `re` module):

```
>>> import re
>>> NAMES_AND_VALUES = re.compile(r'\w+')
>>> OPERATORS = re.compile(r'(?:\+|\*|\-|\/)+')

>>> string = '((a * 5) // ((10 - y) + z))'

>>> NAMES_AND_VALUES.findall(string)
['a', '5', '10', 'y', 'z']

>>> OPERATORS.findall(string)
['*', '//', '-', '+']
```

...and then of course you can just store these return values in `lst1` and `lst2` if you want. Or if `lst1` and `lst2` are pre-existing list objects, you can do `lst1 += ...` and `lst2 += ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
import re
str = '((a * 5) // ((10 - y) + z))'

>> filter(None, re.split (r'[()*+ /-]', str))
['a', '5', '10', 'y', 'z']

>> filter(None, re.split ('[()0-9a-z ]', str))
['*', '//', '-', '+']
```